# How can I access Django models from an app running in a different docker container?

Tags: python, django, docker

I have a django app running in a docker container, attached to a mysql container. Everything is defined a docker-compose file.

Now I need another `filesystem_watcher` container running, that will periodically check a directory on the host. When some files appear in this directory, this app needs to create a new instance of a Django model, and save it to the database.

The only way I can think of to do this is to:

- Have a Django container, with the application code
- Have a container for my `filesystem_watcher`, which will also have the entire Django app
- Attach both to the same mysql container

My `filesystem_watcher` app will import the django models, and use them.

This works, but in this scenario, both the Django app Dockerfile, and the `filesystem_watcher` Dockerfile have entries that copy the entire Django app into both containers. If the source code for the Django app changes, both containers need to be rebuilt.

Is there a better way to do this without copying the Django app into the `filesystem_watcher` container?

Comment: Looks like a X Y problem. Could you tell us what is your primary goal? I mean in addition of the problem description you have made for a specific solution that raise the problem Y. Could you tell us what is the functionality you really need and is missing, the X problem.

Comment: @jlandercy I've been working with Django for quite a while, but most of it has been outside of a docker environment. I run into situations where I need a background process that monitors something, and uses Django models to update the database A LOT. Outside of a docker environment, the python modules for my background process can just import Django models and use them. In a docker environment, the Django code isn't available unless I put it in that container. I'm wondering if there's a better way then adding the docker code to every other container that needs to use Django models

Comment: Ok that is a way toward X. But without knowing what is the monitoring (file, system metrics, logs) about and what is going to be updated a lot we may miss something. You may consider address my request of information as post update instead. So what want you monitor? Can the monitoring be addressed by exposing a volume to the other container or exposing an API in you Django application? Is the constraint to use the model mandatory? Is your application packaged then you can only rebuild the final layers of image. This is all about X which you need to better describe.

Comment: @jlandercy Honestly I don't think what is being monitored, or where it comes from matters. The problem is once an even requires an update to the database, I need some way to access the database using the Django ORM. I do see what you're saying about having Django provide an API (like REST), so that the other containers don't need direct access to the ORM models. That's definitely a good suggestion. Is that the main way people would have containers outside of the main app container update the ORM? Or is it possible, and a good idea to use volumes to mount the ORM model code in all containers?

Comment: Can you run this component on the host (not in a container, since containers can't normally see host files) and have it send updates to the main application via an HTTP API?  That would avoid various "sharing" problems that become tricky.

Comment: Just trying to help here, now the comments are long enough. A post update would be a good thing. Let's say you keep the mistery on what is monitored. Can you answer the other questions as they do have relation to your X problem: Can the monitoring be addressed by exposing a volume to the other container or exposing an API in you Django application? Is the constraint to use the model mandatory? Is your application packaged then you can only rebuild the final layers of image?

Comment: @DavidMaze I don't see the advantage of running the code outside the host, and that doesn't appear to do anything to help with the actual problem of how to use the Django ORM, which would be in a container, in an application running on the host

Comment: @jlandercy I think you're still focusing on the wrong thing. It doesn't matter what's being monitored. It matters how you use the Django ORM to get it into the database. A Django API that lets other containers create Django models without directly using the ORM would work. Is that the preferred/only way? I don't have constraints on which layers I build

Comment: @John, I did not focus on monitoring. I dropped it, and I was the first in this post asking if an API would do the job. Still convinced than the OP is focusing on its Y problem (which happened when he dockerized) and needs to rethink about what he really want to do the X problem.

Comment: @John And yes what is monitored matters. Simply because it will give us clue on how we can solve the problem. Would you say that parsing logs is the same than polling a SNMP deaemon? There are plenty way of monitoring. If the OP does not want to disclose what is monitored at least he could say how it need to be monitored. It is not just about the Django model. The question is broad just trying to narrow it.

Comment: @jlandercy Yes, in this case, monitoring logs is absolutely the same as monitoring SNMP, because in both cases, once you figure out what goes into the database, be it log entries, or info you learned using SNMP, you need a way to actually put it into the database. How to put it into the database when the django app is in a completely different container is the heart of the question - not "how do I monitor stuff?". The question is inherently abstract. It just happened to have a concrete example to demonstrate the problem